# How to animate table by using react-flip-move

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting in stuck with an animation problem by using react-flip-move.

If I animate a list, it works very well

```
render() {
return (
  <FlipMove
    staggerDurationBy={30}
    duration={750}
    delay={30}
    enterAnimation={this.state.enterLeaveAnimation}
    leaveAnimation={this.state.enterLeaveAnimation}
  >
    {this.state.contestant.map((element, id) => {
      return (
        <li onClick={() => this.rotate()} key={element.name}>
          {element.name}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </FlipMove>
);}
```

But if I animate a table, it will not work :(.

```
render() {
return (
  <FlipMove
    staggerDurationBy={30}
    duration={750}
    delay={30}
    enterAnimation={this.state.enterLeaveAnimation}
    leaveAnimation={this.state.enterLeaveAnimation}
  >
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.contestant.map((element, id) => {
          return (
            <tr onClick={() => this.rotate()} key={element.name}>
              <td>{element.name}</td>
              <td>{element.id}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </FlipMove>
);}
```

I can not find the reason :'(. Hope you will support me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Animating the table using react flip move is sometimes difficult since it adds a div in the tbody and causes the thead:nth-child(0) to span 100vw hence destroying the table view. Therefore the best usable method is to render the thead tag and its children first in the FlipMove container and the table structure will be kept

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. On SO Answers should include the exact code necessary to solve the OP's question. An idea about what to do is considered, and welcomed as a comment. Concede updating your post to follow through with the exact code necessary to implement your suggestion in order to avoid deletion by SO as not meeting guidelines. Comments & Answers are both very helpful for visitors. The distinction is a defining characteristic for the functionality of the SO platform as intended. Your explanation is great, which is characteristic of quality answers.

Comment: Also, please use backtics to wrap inline code and code specific values, like `100vw`, `FlipMove`, or `flip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the [FlipMove](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flip-move) on row instead of table, so you need to move `<FlipMove>` inside of `<tbody>`.

Please below code and working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-table-by-using-react-flip-move-68icf) demo.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Flip list</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.addToList()}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.removeFromList()}>Remove</button>
        <table className="data-table">
          <tbody>
            <FlipMove
              staggerDurationBy={30}
              duration={750}
              delay={30}
            >
              {this.state.articles.map(article => (
                <tr key={article.id}>
                  <td>{article.title}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </FlipMove>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This won't work, it will create a container inside tbody and invalidate the table dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the container node type inside the `FlipMove` element, so you can set it as `tbody`:

```
<FlipMove typeName="tbody">
    {data.map((props) => <tr {...props} /> )}
</FlipMove>
```